# More Efficient Method to Replacing Specific Values in a 2D List?

Tags: python, arrays

I am currently working on a cat and mouse program in Python and while I was setting up my board, I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to replace 'placeholders' in my 2d list. Currently I am doing:

```
# setting dimensions and printing all placeholders as '[ . ]'
rows, cols = (6, 10)
board = [['[ . ]' for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]

# manually changing placeholders to add numbers for coordinate system on each side
# changing values of top of board
board[0][0] = '     '
board[0][1] = '  1  '
board[0][2] = '  2  '
board[0][3] = '  3  '
board[0][4] = '  4  '
board[0][5] = '  5  '
board[0][6] = '  6  '
board[0][7] = '  7  '
board[0][8] = '  8  '
board[0][9] = '     '
# changes left side of board
board[1][0] = '  1  '
board[2][0] = '  2  '
board[3][0] = '  3  '
board[4][0] = '  4  '
board[5][0] = '     '
```

and so on for the right side and bottom of board. Eventually the board looks like:
[empty playing board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytJlI.png)

I would imagine there is a more efficient method to do this but I am unsure of how I would do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The solution below uses the `numpy` library as it's an excellent (if not *the*) library to use for matrix manipulation.  You may or may not be familliar with it, so I've tried to use more explicit code and commented accordingly.

The example code uses two functions:

- `build()` To build the initial playing board.
- `show()` To display the playing board, at any stage of the game.

Future Development:
I've left a couple bits for you to develop on your own. Some ideas are:

- The code can be optimised into a `class`.
- Include a `move()` function which can update the board with each player's move. But I'll leave this small project up to you to research and implement.

#### Example Code:

```
import numpy as np

def build() -> np.ndarray:
    """Build the board.
    
    Returns:
        A new playing board as a ``np.ndarray``.
    
    """
    # Board configuration.
    cols = 8
    rows = 4
    # Create horizontal, vertical and dot lists.
    h = list(range(0, cols+1)) + [0]
    v = list(range(0, rows+1)) + [0]
    d = ['.' for i in range(1, cols+1)]
    # Initialise a new (empty) matrix of size.
    m = np.zeros([rows+2, cols+2], dtype=str)
    # Populate vertical labels.
    m[:, 0] = np.array(v)
    m[:, -1] = np.array(v)
    # Populate horizontal labels.
    m[0, :] = np.array(h)
    m[-1, :] = np.array(h)
    # Populate dots.
    m[1:-1, 1:-1] = np.array(d)
    # Replace remaining zeros with a space.
    m[m == '0'] = ' '
    # Return the new playing board.
    return m

def show(board):
    """Display the ndarray as a board.
    
    Args:
        board (np.ndarray): Board to be displayed.
    
    """
    for row in board:
        print(' '.join(row))

# Create and show a new playing board.
board = build()
show(board=board)
```

#### New Board:

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  
1 . . . . . . . . 1
2 . . . . . . . . 2
3 . . . . . . . . 3
4 . . . . . . . . 4
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

#### Play!:

I'm not sure how the game is played, but let's say each player takes a turn below, Player1 is `x` and Player2 is `o`.

The board is updated with each player's piece.

```
# Update `board` for [row, col]
board[1, 3] = 'x'
board[3, 6] = 'o'

# Show the updated board.
show(board=board)
```

#### Updated Board:

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  
1 . . x . . . . . 1
2 . . . . . . . . 2
3 . . . . . o . . 3
4 . . . . . . . . 4
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: So I am not very familiar with numpy but obviously it appears it is the more efficient method. But since I am not too comfortable with using numpy I have just simplified my initial method by: `board[0][0:10] = '    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8    ' ` for the top of the board and so on. The next step would be to determine the playing part, for which I have to use a .csv file that has coordinates to set the board up with. I just need to figure out how to associate those coordinates with my empty board.

Answer (score 1):

You could use two loops for top/bottom and right/left walls, then just manually set the corners:

```py
rows, cols = (6, 10)
board = [['[ . ]' for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]

for i in range(1, rows-1):
    board[i][0] = board[i][cols-1] = f'  {i}  '

for j in range(1, cols-1):
    board[0][j] = board[rows-1][j] = f'  {j}  '

board[0][0] = board[0][cols-1] = board[rows-1][0] = board[rows-1][cols-1] = '     '
```

And to print it you can use: `print(*(' '.join(row) for row in board), sep='\n')` which gives:

```
        1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8        
  1   [ . ] [ . ] [ . ] [ . ] [ . ] [ . ] [ . ] [ . ]   1  
  2   [ . ] [ . ] [ . ] [ . ] [ . ] [ . ] [ . ] [ . ]   2  
  3   [ . ] [ . ] [ . ] [ . ] [ . ] [ . ] [ . ] [ . ]   3  
  4   [ . ] [ . ] [ . ] [ . ] [ . ] [ . ] [ . ] [ . ]   4  
        1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
```

---

You can also squeeze it to one loop, by checking the indexes:

```py
for i in range(1, max(rows, cols)-1):
    val = f'  {i}  '
    if i < rows-1:
        board[i][0] = board[i][cols-1] = val
    if i < cols-1:
        board[0][i] = board[rows-1][i] = val
```